# Using different bluetooth mouses and keyboards on a MacBook

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

I was wondering if it is possible to get a wireless mouse and keyboard less expensive than Apple's that would still work the way Apple's do - without the need to use extra USB toggles for bluetooth connection?

My MacBook Air has only 2 USB ports and connecting a mouse and a keyboard would leave me without either one or both USB ports.

I know it might be reasonable to buy some device to get 'more' USB ports, but I'd like to find out if there are any mouses and keyboards on a market that a MacBook would recognize *without* the need to use their own USB bluetooth adapters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any bluetooth mouse/keyboard should work with the Mac's built in bluetooth.  I use a Logitech bluetooth mouse with my MBP.  Some are marketed as Mac specific, but even a Windows targeted Bluetooth mouse/keyboard should work.

Comment: @Jason and you don't even use the built in USB thing?

Comment: There is a difference between a wireless mouse/keyboard (which require their own special adapter) and a Bluetooth one (which will work with any PC/Mac that already has bluetooth).

Comment: Is there some special reason other than price you don't want to use Apple's wireless keyboard and mouse?

Comment: @TomGewecke yep, the price is _the_ reason

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You just need a proper mouse/keyboard that is intended to work that way (via bluetooth).
I know that logitech actually has some of these.
A quick research give me [this](http://www.logitech.com/it-it/product/5747?crid=7) or [this](http://www.logitech.com/it-it/product/bluetooth-illuminated-keyboard-k810?crid=26).